# Can't create an EditText with multiple lines & no spelling suggestions on 2.3.4

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I've been trying for weeks and I haven't been able to get an EditText to use multiple lines **and** have no spelling suggestions.

I need to put in different languages, so the autocorrect definitely can't be turned on, but it seems to interfere with letting it run multiple lines.

I can get either of them to work, but not both at the same time.

I've tried:

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

and

```
.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

and many other methods I found on Google and here at SO none have worked. Maybe it's specific to my OS version? Is this a known error?

Answer (score 4):

I've just tried this myself on a 2.3.4 device and for me your code is showing no suggestions:

```
EditText testView = new EditText(context);
testView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
mainLayout.addView(testView);
```

So this issue could be specific to the device you are testing on.

However you could try using setRawInputType() instead of setInputType().

You could also try using the flag InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD which should not display any suggestions whatsoever:

```
testView.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Comment: setRawInputType fixed the bug I encountered - When I was setting setInputType I lost the multi line capabilities of the AutoCompleteTextView no matter what the type value was.